# Android 6.0 se cierra app al intentar abrir camara

Tags: android-studio, android-permissions

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al darle en permitir me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- 1.- Hay dispositivos en los que me manda Superposición de pantalla, lo cual no quiero. **¿Como solucionar esto?**
- 2.- En otros dispotivos *Samsung* definitivamente se cierra al abrir cámara, Ojo! no puedo debugear esto debido a que los celulares de pruebas no los tengo.

  ```
  private static String APP_DIRECTORY = "MyPictureApp/";
  private static String MEDIA_DIRECTORY = APP_DIRECTORY + "PictureApp";
  private final int MY_PERMISSIONS = 100;
  private final int PHOTO_CODE = 200;
  private final int SELECT_PICTURE = 300;
  private String mPath;
  ```

  Boton para abrir un dialog Camara/Galeria

  ```
  if(mayRequestStoragePermission()){
                  seleccionarMedio();
  }
  ```

  *Seleccionamos de que medio sera Galeria/Camara*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void seleccionarMedio() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        //vista que contiene el diseño
        View login_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vista_foto,null);
        //botones de seleccion de tipo de captura
        LinearLayout Galeria = (LinearLayout)login_layout.findViewById(R.id.botonGaleria);
        LinearLayout Tomar = (LinearLayout)login_layout.findViewById(R.id.botonTomar);
        //Creacion de AlertDialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Selecciona una foto");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Puedes tomar una foto o cargar una antes previamente tomada");
        alertDialog.setView(login_layout);

        //Botones dentro del alertDialog
        final AlertDialog show = alertDialog.show();
        Galeria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            //Cerrar dialogo para evitar que se mantenga una ves tomada la foto
            show.dismiss();

        }
    });

    Tomar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


         //openCamera();
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Reporte_App.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Reporte_App.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Reporte_App.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 110);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 22);
                    }
                    show.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

*Result*

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
    opts.inSampleSize = 2;   // for 1/2 the image to be loaded

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
            case PHOTO_CODE:
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[]{mPath}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                            }
                        });

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                Fotografia.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Imagen =((BitmapDrawable) Fotografia.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                verificadores[1].setText("Listo (Capturada)");
                break;
            case SELECT_PICTURE:
                Uri path = data.getData();
                Fotografia.setImageURI(path);
                Imagen =((BitmapDrawable) Fotografia.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                verificadores[1].setText("Listo (De Galeria)");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

*PermissionResult*

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS){
            if(grantResults.length == 2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(Reporte_App.this, "Permisos aceptados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            showExplanation();
        }
    }
```

*Mensaje de alerta*

```
private void showExplanation() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Reporte_App.this);
    builder.setTitle("Permisos denegados");
    builder.setMessage("Para usar las funciones de la app necesitas aceptar los permisos");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

> ¿Posible error?
>   Quisiera que le pusieran un ojo a la parte de los permisos y ver si realmente todo esta declarado de forma correcta. Espero su ayuda.
>
> Intentando de forma manual
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>   Al parecer todo el problema viene de aquí.
>
> Update ERROR!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: desarrolladoresalpha.tocumbomovil, PID: 2654
              android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyPictureApp/PictureApp/1516757788.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                  at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
                  at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
                  at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:845)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8941)
                  at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8926)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                  at desarrolladoresalpha.tocumbomovil.App_Reportes.Reporte_App.openCamera(Reporte_App.java:276)
                  at desarrolladoresalpha.tocumbomovil.App_Reportes.Reporte_App.access$200(Reporte_App.java:77)
                  at desarrolladoresalpha.tocumbomovil.App_Reportes.Reporte_App$9.onClick(Reporte_App.java:322)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes manualmente permitir al superposición de pantalla desde los settings.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Programaticamente asigna los permisos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: necesito manipular esto de manera transparente, ¿habrá una forma?

Comment: A que te refieres de manera transparente?

Comment: Hola jorgesys, porfin pude debugear en un dispositivo con android, he añadido el error. saludos!